# Is "What happened to him" correct?

Tags: infinitives, verb-forms, past-participles

It is common to say "What happened to him (or somebody)?" to inquire about somebodies' whereabouts. But is it right?

In my opinion, it should be "What *was* happened to him?" or "What *did* happen to him?", even it can be "What had happen to him (*before today*)?" Am I wrong in this understanding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Happen** is the infinitive/present form of the verb; **happen*ed*** is its past/past participle form.

So *What happened?* is the form you would normally use to ask what occurred in the past.

*What was happened?* would be a past passive and can't be said in English, unless you're inventing a new transitive use of *happen*.

And *What had happen?* is not a possible construction; you must ask *What has happen**ed**?* (if for instance you are arriving at a scene of confusion) or *What had happen**ed**?* (if you are trying to find out what happened before some event in the past).

*What did happen* is possible; you would use this if people have been denying that this, that or the other happened and you want to steer the conversation away from what did **not** happen.

Answer (score 2):

As for why is "What happened to him?" instead of "What did happened to him?" or "What did happen to him?" the answer is given in a question I asked on EL&U: ["Who turned off the lights?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/who-turned-off-the-lights)

As for the tense to use, the OALD has the following examples for "happen to somebody/something."

> I hope nothing **has happened** to them.
>   It's the best thing that **has** ever **happened** to me.
>   What'**s happened** to your car?
>   Do you know what **happened** to Gill Lovecy?

The used tense is always the simple past, or the present perfect.